# How to dynamically add a custom directive to a div element?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm a beginner at angularjs, please take it easy on me. So I have this directive and would like to dynamically append it to a div element. How should I do it?

```
appDirectives.directive('test', function () {
    return  {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'templates/test.html'
    }
});
```

I tried this but it didn't work. I'm assuming the template didn't get compiled before I appended to the div element. Is there an angular way to do this?

```
<div id="element"></div>

$('#element').append(<test></test>);
```

**Update:** Here is what I'm trying to do. When a user logged in my page, I have 3 different templates that I would like it to show up depend on the type of of user.
The 3 templates are `<basic>, <regular>, <advance>`
Basically after user logged in, I would have the value of a variable `user.type` and would like to show the appropriate template for that user.

Any suggestions would help. Thank you :)

Comment: You shouldn't try to dynamically add directives or modify the DOM at runtime, that doesn't work well with Angular. Could you describe exactly what you are trying to do? There's probably a proper Angular-way to do it.

Comment: no possible to add dyanamic directives with angular

Comment: The template is a custom view of a chat box. If user wants to add more chat box, user can click on a button to add more chat box onto the screen. Is there an angular way to do this?

Comment: Create an array which contains the contents of the chat box. Each chat box content is an item in the array. Using `ng-repeat`, just loop over the array items (essentially looping over the different chats) and render the chat boxes to the UI. When the user adds a chat box, simply add an empty string / empty content item to this array which will dynamically add more chat boxes.

Comment: Hi, would you please provide ideas on my new proposed API to make programmatically adding directives a simpler process? https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6950 Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Something like this, may be?  http://plnkr.co/edit/SmL9fA5GzAxI2WYTnYZy

Angular way is to represent the view by javascript object (in the scope)
 and let Angular templating system to refrect your model.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It solved one of the problems that I have. I just updated my question with a different problem. Would you mind taking a look at it?

Comment: I think Mark's answer is the best.  I doubt that you want to use custom directive though.  You can simply use direct html if templates are simple, or use ng-include if they are long.

Answer (score 3):

[ng-switch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch) is probably what you want:

```
<div id="element" ng-switch on="user.type">
  <span ng-switch-when="basic"><basic></basic></span>
  <span ng-switch-when="regular"><regular></regular></span>
  <span ng-switch-when="advance"><advance></advance></span>
</div>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2s56IKx6uSX0WMXDMKRx?p=preview)