# create empty element in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need to create an empty element to be used as angular directive in DOM.

```
<mydirective></mydirective>
```

How should I do it programmatically?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you elaborate with the code you have tried?

Comment: If I have to create a 'input' element, I write "document.createElement("input")". I want to know how to create an element which is any custom element and not a 'input' or a 'div' or any standard element.

Comment: @user2599052 still there are lot more question arises..what you want exactly..please elaborate more

Comment: Do you mean you want to dynamically inject your custom directive into the DOM?

Comment: I think I found my answer. document.createElement("mydirective") will work. I was under the impression that createElement() method only creates standard HTML elements.

Comment: @MattHerbstritt : yes, thats what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a few ways. Take a look at [How to dynamically add a custom directive to a div element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184557/how-to-dynamically-add-a-custom-directive-to-a-div-element)

Using ng-switch as Mark Rajcok suggests is probably the easiest way:

```
<div id="element" ng-switch on="user.type">
  <span ng-switch-when="basic"><basic></basic></span>
  <span ng-switch-when="regular"><regular></regular></span>
  <span ng-switch-when="advance"><advance></advance></span>
</div>
```

Using document.createElement() may work like you say but it's really not the angular way.